# Is there's a way to protect my slideshow images

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I don't want to use flash because it won't allow me to dynamically modify (add, remove) the pictures through my application so I thought about javascript (JQuery Plugins). but the problem is visitors can save the pictures and I don't want that to happen! .. so any ideas ?

**Edit**
I really appreciate your help and honesty but is JavaScript to have a dynamic modifiable SlideShow for my websites ? .. I don't care about screenshots, what's important is the original picture that I think will be downloaded to the visitor temp files!

Comment: Watermark them maybe? There's nothing stopping people from taking screenshots no matter what you use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do is a mild deterrent.  I've written an HTML5 slideshow used by many.  It offers right-click warning to those using it, but it is best referred to as a warning rather than a protection.

First off, if a browser can display an image, any viewer can get them too - no matter what you do - that's just the way the web works.  If you really need them protected, then you need to use a significant semi-transparent watermark that touches important parts of the image or limit the viewing only to people who you trust.

If you're interested in a mild deterrent that can still be bypassed quickly by anyone who understands how a browser works, but might slow down non-sophisticated users, then you can implement a couple forms of click protection that make it harder to right-click save your images.   Right click protection works best when the actual image you are displaying is not the top level image.  This can be done by displaying a transparent image over the top of your slides.  This will not be seen, but if a viewer succeeds in getting to a right-click-save menu, all they will succeed in saving is the empty transparent image on top.  You can literally use a 1x1 transparent gif image which is tiny and then scale it up to the size of your image to cover it.  It will not be seen, but it will defeat right-click save.

It is also common to also put in some javascript that attempts to intercept the right-click operation to prevent that, though this protection is blocked by more and more browsers now (like Firefox 4+) and is far from foolproof.  It should not be relied upon.

In the end, these extra steps are only a mild deterrent and will only work with non-sophisticated viewers who aren't very determined.  Because, even with the maximum protection in place, one can still look at the media list in the browser and see all the image URLs in the web page or look at the source or DOM or network trace of the web page to see what the URL is of the images that are being displayed.  Once the URLs are known, the images can be saved easily.  The danger of this kind of protection is that content owners believe it's real protection and they put images at risk that they shouldn't (without good watermarks on them).  But, if you fully understand what you're getting (and not getting), you can do it.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to **Really** protect them. If the user can see the image, then the user's browser has downloaded it. So the user has the image on their computer and can do anything they want with it.

There are lots of ways of making it harder for the user though. Disabling right clicking is one way.

If you really need to hide them badly you could use the data uri scheme too, but it really won't stop someone who really wants to get it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: the visitors will be a regular internet user he's not much of an expert or a hacker but I'll try to read the article .. btw I hope u'd check my edit :)

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to protect your images unless you use a watermark which not what you're looking for as I understand you.

You need to remember that the user will always have his printscreen button and many tools that can do the job and that you can't control anyway

Answer (score 2):

Break up your images into pieces, or possibly even embed them in larger junk images.  Then use CSS to display the multiple overlapping divs with appropriate background styles to position the pieces where they need to be so to the user they look like one image, kinda like how google maps looks like one large image but is actually made up of many small ones.  The user won't know the difference, but if they try to save them locally they'll just get one piece at a time.

Of course, that only works until they realize they can do a print-screen, but it's something.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to completely protect your images.

Seriously, if the user can see it in their browser they can save it to their computer.

You are fighting a losing battle here.

Even if you watermark your images, a good graphics program can countact that.

The best thing to do is only display small, low quality images that people wouldn't want to keep anyway.